# AccessViolationException when passing pointer to native function

Tags: c#, interop

I'm trying to pass a pointer of a struct from my C# code to a native function. I tried to pin the memory of the struct, but I get a AccessViolationException around 25% of the time I run the program.

**Here's the basic code without any marshalling/pinning:**

---

The struct:

```
public struct Foo
{
  private uint x;
  private uint y;
}
```

---

The native funtion signature:

```
[DllImport(LibraryName, EntryPoint = "FooBar", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern unsafe void Bar(Foo* data);
```

---

The calling function:

```
public void CallingFunction()
{
  unsafe
  {
    Foo data = new Foo();
    Bar(&data);
  }
}
```

---

**What I've tried so far:**

Option 1 (GCHandle.Alloc):

```
// In CallingFunction:
Foo data = new Foo();
GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(data, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr ptr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
Foo* fooPtr = (Foo*)ptr.ToPointer();
Bar(fooPtr);
handle.Free();
```

---

Option 2 (MarshalAs in native function signature):

```
public static extern unsafe void Bar([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] Foo* data);
```

---

Option 3 (Marshal.AllocHGlobal):

```
// In CallingFunction:
Foo* data = (Foo*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(Foo));
Bar(data);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal((IntPtr)data);
```

---

Option 4 (KeepAlive):

```
// At the end of CallingFunction():
GC.KeepAlive(data);
```

---

With every option I still get the AccessViolationException. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: is `Bar` a sync API? or does it continue running in the background? or in other words: is the pointer required to be valid for longer than just the API call? If it **isn't** (which is very common in most APIs - pretty much the default) - what you have should be fine. A struct on the stack is effectively pre-pinned; that you have should be fine. So ... are you sure that the size of the struct is correct? If the pointer is expected to outlive that call, then it gets much more complex. Is there a clear statement about what `Bar` expects?

Comment: also, why are you marshalling it as LPArray when it isn't array-like? Does `Bar` expect a C-style array of exactly 2 elements? or...?

Comment: @MarcGravell: The pointer doesn't need to outlive the API call. The native Bar function expects just the Foo*, so just the pointer to the struct. The signature is basically just: 
void Bar(Foo* data)

Comment: @MarcGravell I used  LPArray because I'm out of ideas and I thought maybe I can marshall it as standard C array (BYTE*). Thanks for your comments!

Comment: It does not have anything to do with pinning, the pinvoke marshaler already does that.  You need to debug the C++ code to find the real cause.  If you did not write this code yourself then send a small repro to the author so he can debug it for you.

Comment: @HansPassant Yeah I will need to talk with the maintainer of the native code, seems to be my only option. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try following :

```
        [DllImport(LibraryName, EntryPoint = "FooBar", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern void Bar(IntPtr data);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Foo data = new Foo();
            IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(data));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(data, ptr, true);

            Bar(ptr);
        }

        public struct Foo
        {
            private uint x;
            private uint y;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sadly I had no success, I still get AccessViolationException.

Comment: How is the native function defined?  Does device expect one Foo or an array of Foo?  An Array of Foo would expect a '\0' to terminate the array.  So the first time it will work because memory is always initialized to zero.  Then later after the memory gets used you may not get a zero at the end of the array.  The other reason for intermittent happen with the micro alignment.  The alignment could be wrong between the compiler options in c# and the native code.  Check native code to see if it is x86, 16/32 bit or 64 bit.

Comment: It excpects one Foo pointer. Yeah I will need to talk with the maintainer of the native code, seems to be my only option. Thanks!

Comment: Does native return a value?  Are integers 32 bit?  Change to CallingConvention.Cdecl if c language.  Standard only works with Windows calling convention.